# Laravel 8 chunk memory leak

Tags: laravel, memory, batch-processing, chunking

I have an artisan command that is scheduler to run every 15 minutes to update a model calculated field. The command process thousands of rows and ends up eating all of the memory.

My understanding of the laravel documentation is that using the `chunk` method reduces greatly the memory usage when iterating over lots of rows because it only keeps N number of rows in memory at a time instead of the whole dataset. This is the method I am already using, but every additional processed chunks increase the memory consumption of the docker container.

Here is the original code:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->openingHourArraySerialiser = new OpeningHourArraySerializer();
}

public function handle()
{
    $this->openingHours = OpeningHour::with('scheduleHours')->get();
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    $this->getTicketQuery()->chunk(500, function($tickets) {
        $cases = [];
        $ids = [];
        $params = [];
        foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
            $cases[] = "WHEN {$ticket->ID} then ?";
            $openingHourSchedule = $this->getOpeningHoursSchedule($ticket);
            $params[] = TicketPriorityLevelCalculator::calculate($ticket, $openingHourSchedule);
            $ids[] = $ticket->ID;
        }
        $ids = implode(',', $ids);
        $cases = implode(' ', $cases);
        if (!empty($ids)) {
            DB::connection('tcollect')->update("UPDATE _DSKTickets SET PriorityLevel = CASE ID {$cases} END WHERE ID in ({$ids})", $params);
        }
    });
    $this->setTicketWithoutDueDatePriority();
}

private function getOpeningHoursSchedule($ticket)
{
    $openingHours = $this->openingHours->where('ID', $ticket->OpeningHoursID)->first();
    return $openingHours->getSerializedSchedule($this->openingHourArraySerialiser);
}
```

I have read from other thread suggesting to disable the query log.
I have also set the `APP_DEBUG` to false.

The following image is a graph of the memory consumption before and after.

It reached 1gb and dies (I manually killed the process at 500mb for faster testing of my modifications)

[image: Memory usage graph]

I have also tried:

- to use the `chunkById` method.
- to use `lazy` and `lazyById` methods
- unset cases, ids, params and tickets variables

It result in the same memory consumption.
I cannot use the `cursor` method because I need to eager load relations.

How can I reduce the memory usage to never reach the 1gb limit?

Comment: Just as a side note, you should not be interpolating strings directly into your database query. Use the query builder methods such as `table()`, `update()` and `where()` individually, making use of the placeholder features they offer.